# Can I bypass the hard coding in Pandas/Python and set a line-terminator of my choice?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have a super dirty text-heavy dataset. While the various column values are tab-separated but there are many line breaks within the desired row of data.
All data entries are separated by a hard '\n' notation.

I tried Setting the `lineterminator` argument as `'\n'`, but it is still reading the line breaks as a new row.
Performing any sort of regex or related operation is most likely resulting in loss of tab separations, which I need to load my data into a dataframe. Also doing a word-wise of line-wise operation is not exactly feasible owing to the size of the dataset.

Is there a way I can get the Pandas not to read the line breaks as a new row, and go to the new line only when it sees a *'\n'*?

Snapshot of my data:
[The unprocessed dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX5sv.png)

Below is a quick look at the current state:
[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg6oi.png)

The highlighted red box should be one entry.

Comment: Try setting the line terminator to `'\\n'`

Comment: What do you mean by "a hard '\n' notation"?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I meant there is an actual '\n' written on the text file.

Comment: @Mike67 it is giving me an error `ValueError: Only length-1 line terminators supported`

Comment: Please explain better what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could preprocess to a proper TSV and then read it from there. Use `itertools.groupby` to find the "\N" endings. If there are other problems with this file, such as internal tabs not being escaped, all bets are off.

```
import itertools
import re

separator_re = re.compile(r"\s*\\N\s*$", re.MULTILINE)

with open('other.csv') as infp:
    with open('other-conv.csv', 'w') as outfp:
        for hassep, subiter in itertools.groupby(infp, separator_re.search):
            if hassep:
                outfp.writelines("{}\n".format(separator_re.sub("",line))
                    for line in subiter)
            else:
                for line in subiter:
                    if line.endswith("\\\n"):
                        line = line[:-2] + " "
                    else:
                        line = line.strip()
                    outfp.write(line)
```

Comment: I changed the encoding and dropped a few entries that were throwing error. Other than that it seems to be working fine. Cheers!